# Why is this a pole?

Tags: complex-analysis

My introductory course in complex analysis has an example problem to evaluate
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\sin(\pi x)}{x^2+2x+5}\text{ d}x$$ using the Residue Theorem. The solution includes

> Let $p(z)=z, \; q(z)=z^2+2z+5, \; \phi(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}, \; f(z)=\phi(z)e^{i\pi z}=\frac{ze^{i\pi z}}{z^2+1}$. The function $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ except for simple poles at $-1\pm2i$.

Why is this? As far as I can see, those points aren't zeros of $z^2+1$, and I don't know how else to recognise poles of a function not in the form $\frac{g(x)}{(z-\alpha)^k}$ except by finding the Laurent series.

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.  Perhaps the same question was asked in a previous semester but with $x^2 + 1$ in the denominator.  Does the solution proceed to analyse the function $z e^{i \pi z}/(z^2 + 1)$, or does it analyse the actual integrand in the problem statement?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert It goes on with $z^2+2z+5$. I think you're right that it's a typo.

Comment: Yep. It's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a typo: $f(z)=\phi(z)e^{i\pi z}=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}e^{i\pi z}=\frac{ze^{i\pi x}}{z^2+2z+5}$

where $-1\pm2i$ are poles of $q(z)=z^2+2z+5$